# suspecious TCP connection Port 60000

Tags: networking

In my wireshark pcap file for the first time in last few months I saw that there is transfer of lot of data over TCP port 60000, 60002, 60004, 60008. One side IP address belongs to otx.alienvault.com. But as per [this](https://www.speedguide.net/port.php?port=60000) & [This](https://www.auditmypc.com/tcp-port-60000.asp) website port 60000 is used by trojan/ backdoors/ deep throat etc. I am unable to trace the application using this port.

```
3295    2021-09-02 06:50:19.696773242   99.XX.XX.XX 100.XX.XX.XXX   TCP 74  443 → 60000 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=65535 Len=0 MSS=1440 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=143274654 TSecr=613246749 WS=512
```

On [This](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskNetsec/comments/995ruy/quick_question_about_port_60000_and_60001/) link one suggest "Track down what machines are listening or using those ports and map those connections/ports back to their process ID."  But how I don't know.

```
3391    2021-09-02 06:50:19.817344087   99.XX.XX.XX 100.XX.XX.XXX   TLSv1.3 1494    Application Data [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
```

These were different ports 60000, 60002, 60004, 60008. I completely layman. Please help me.

The MAC addresses showing are not MAC address of my laptop. these are MAC addresses of some devices in network.
Ethernet II, Src: XX:XX:XX:XX:38:8e (XX:XX:XX:XX:38:8e), Dst: XX:XX:XX:XX:09:a9 (XX:XX:XX:XX:09:a9)

Comment: This web site explains what the web site you have noted is. https://cybersecurity.att.com/resource-center/webcasts/how-to-use-otx-with-ossim It appears you are using their services?

Comment: BTW did you even bother to google that URL?

Comment: Yes I googled. But as far as I remember I never opt to register at otx.alienvault.com. Otherwise the dst and src MAc addresses are not of my device these are devices somewhere in LAN network (may be of service provider). I am searching my root directory for {sudo ag "60000/tcp" /}